# Casting to a button control (Android): what exactly is that?

Tags: java, android, controls

The available (similar) questions on "casting" don't really clarify what this is or does (just started Android programming, by the way). Where and how does one notice the effect of "casting"?

What is the difference between:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_second)
```

and

```
Button b = findViewById(R.id.btn_second)
```

?

Kind regards,

Pieter

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
findViewById(R.id.btn_second)  will return a View.
```

But what kind of view it is, a Button, a List, a TextView, EditView, etc.

Here findViewById(R.id.btn_second) is returning a View of type Button, so we to cast it to Button type.

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_second);
```

Ok i will give you an example.

```
public abstract class Animal{
    public abstract void sound();
}

public class Dog extends Animal{
    public void sound(){
        System.out.println("Wooffffff");
    }
}

public class Cat extends Animal{
    public void sound(){
        System.out.println("Meowwwwwwww");
    }
}
```

Now if i create 1 dog  and 1 cat object..

```
Dog d = new Dog();
Cat c = new Cat();

public class CloneAnimal{

    public void doIt(Animal a){
        if(a instanceof Dog)
            Dog d1 = (Dog) a;
        else 
            Cat c1 = (Cat) a ;
    }
}
```

(Dog) and (Cat) are explicit cast, like (Button).

Answer (score 0):

This is a Java inheritance question.

the method findViewByID returns an object of type View.  All of the widget classes inherit from View, so we say that "A Button IS A View"

You cannot assign a View object to a Button reference.  The cast operator is telling the compiler "I'm really sure that this View object happens to be a Button"

If this isn't making sense, you need to review a tutorial on inheritance, and casting of reference objects.

Comment: It is starting to make more sense now that I found this: Thinking in Java, 3rd ed. Revision 4.0, 1: Introduction to Objects.

Answer (score 0):

In Java object typecasting, one object reference can be type cast into another object reference. The cast can be to its own class type or to one of its subclass or superclass types or interfaces. There are compile-time rules and runtime rules for casting in java.

The cast operator (type) is used to convert values from one type to another or to change an object reference to a compatible type.

Answer (score 0):

Types isn't a unique to Android, and is something that you want to get a good understanding of if you want to do Object Oriented Programming well. I'd recommend reading up on [inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion), [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming), and [type conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming). These will help give you an understanding in why we use types of objects that we do.

To answer your question, Android UI objects all derive from a type called `View` (docs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html)). This defines an interface, i.e. what all objects of this type must be capable of doing, such as being able to 'draw' itself. This allows Android to work with any type of displayable object as long as it implements/extends the `View` interface, so you can create your own custom UI objects and Android doesn't need to know about the fact it is a new type, only that it can interact with it like any other `View` object.

In your question, you're [downcasting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting), where you're being more specific about the object's type so that you can interact with the object in a different way using the defined interface of the type you're downcasting to. Upcasting is going the other way, where you're making a specialised object more generic, providing it is a sub-type of that type, meaning it implements the same interface.