# First time with Android Studio, having one small surprise on "Error:(24cannot find symbol class button

Tags: java, android

I am following this [course](https://www.skillshare.com/classes/Create-an-Android-App-in-34-Minutes-%E2%9C%85/1642579370/classroom/discussions?enrolledRedirect=1) and did my best. However when I try to run my code it says

> "Error:(24, 19) error: cannot find symbol class button"

Does this mean that I have not defined where to find button ?

It looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSiLZ.jpg

I greatly appreciate any feedback ! :D

Comment: it's `Button` (with an upper case B) names are case sensitive in Java (as in most programming languages)

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). Also, instead of posting images of your code, please copy paste it in your question (with proper formating)

Answer (score 1):

In below line you are trying to cast to a variable name(`button`), which **cannot be done**.

```
button = (button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

Should be:

```
button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
```

When casting always remember to add data type(in this case class name) inside the parantheses`()`. Otherwise you will get syntax error like that.

Why, you will get syntax error?

`findViewById(int id);` which returns the `View` of that id you have specified. And your `button` variable data-type is `Button`. So to avoid **uncompatible error** you need to cast to match both side.

Also read: [Why do i have to cast a Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14881606/why-do-i-have-to-cast-a-button), [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967251/casting-to-a-button-control-android-what-exactly-is-that) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736187/button-button-findviewbyidr-id-button-always-resolves-to-null-in-android-stu).

Comment: FYI: you cannot `cast to your button variable name` as it makes no sense technically.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski, thats what exactly im saying. cannot cast to variable name and that should be class name

Answer (score 0):

That line should read

`button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);`

`findViewById` returns an item of class `View` and your button variable has a type of `Button`. Since `Button` is a child of `View` you can cast it to `Button`.

Comment: no, that's irrelevant in his case and no longer the case if compiled with recent SDKs either

Comment: Thank you both for the feedback ! It works :) I am very thankful for the assistance, the feeling of seeing "build complete" was very satisfying !